# Do multiple calls to the Firebase Database return in the order they were called?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In an iOS Twitter like app that I am building with Firebase, I make an initial call to the backend to receive the newest 20 "Tweets" for a user's newsfeed in `viewDidLoad()`.

In order to fetch older Tweets after the 20th newest Tweet, I would like to use `UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching` in iOS 10 to fetch these older "Tweets" as a user scrolls down.

Using `UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching`, I will be able to anticipate when a user will want to see older tweets and I can then make a call to the backend to fetch them.

If I were to make multiple calls to the database in quick succession to fetch different tweets, such as to get the 25th newest tweet and then get the 26th newest tweet, does Firebase guarantee that I will receive the calls back in the correct order?

E.g. the oldest call to the database always comes back first, followed by the second oldest etc. So that I can guarantee the order of the tweets displayed is correct by simply inserting them into my data model without having to worry about checking the timestamp for each tweet.

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase Database client interacts with its server over a single open connection. So in general the items will be returned in the order in which you request them.

But due to the nature of asynchronous code, there are some interesting edge cases that (while they don't violate what I said above) may cause problems in your app.

Without seeing your code, it's hard to say anything more.